# How to know if an iOS 5 app will work on iOS 6 without changing Xcode version?

Tags: ios5, ios6, xcode4.3, compatibility

How can i check the compatibility of my application, based on IOS 5.0.1 created with Xcode 4.3.3 on Lion, on IOS 6 without having to change my current MAC OS version and Xcode? Is there any way? And as an addition to this question, if i submit my application to the Apple Store, can it be rejected just for the simple reason of being created compatible with IOS 5 and not with IOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear what you mean by “compatible”. One thing is the version of the SDK you link against, one thing is your Deployment Target setting and then there’s actual code compatibility regarding various API, UI and behaviour differences between iOS 5 and 6.

- [It seems](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/41104) that you have to develop with at least the iOS 6 SDK to submit your app at all.
- However, your Deployment Target setting may go as low as required, so that your app still supports older iOS versions.
- Your app doesn’t have to be “compatible” with iOS 6 in the sense that you tested it on iOS 6 and handled all the potential quirks that may have appeared by moving from iOS 5 to iOS 6. Of course, the user experience on iOS 6 could suffer in this case, but unless there’s a major bug, the reviewer doesn’t care.

Comment: What i meant, can i be rejected just because developed my application using IOS 5 and not IOS 6?
I read this blog you linked too, i know that i can set my deployment target to whatever i want, but can i be rejected just for the simple fact that i have not developed my application based on IOS 6?

Comment: What does it mean to “develop an app using iOS 5”? If you mean having iOS 5 as the Base SDK setting in Xcode, then yes, it seems that the app will not get past the review. (Apple generally doesn’t want developers using older SDK releases to push the adoption forward.)

Comment: Thank you @zoul its a bit of bad news but it has to be taken under consideration

Comment: It’s good to get used to it, although it’s a bit of a pain. Happy to help.